# Issue in Updating the IP in DB

Tags: wordpress, rds

We encountered below listed issue while migrating our company site to new site following the steps below:

1. We have launched new Amazon RDS instance and imported the data from old DB to new RDS.
2. We pointed website to newly launched RDS
3. Assigned new Elastic IP Address to WordPress site and the IP of the instance got change.
4. Ran a Query to Update New IP in database level

but even after executing the query the prod site still pointed to old IP.

Fix:

1. We have taken DB dump in .sql format and analysed. We found that the old URL is still hard coded in the DB
2. So we have edited the .sql dump by replacing old URL with new URL. And imported the edited dump to DB. After the import and restarting, application started working fine.

Could someone please let me know (1) whether such hard coding IP is a common practice in WP and (2) Is there a better way to do this to avoid hard coding?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

WordPress does not normally store a server IP address in the database, but it **does** store the full URL to the site in many places.

It sounds like you must be using an IP address to access the website, meaning that people visit the site by going to http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx and not http://www.example.com, which would explain why the IP address is being stored in the database.

When migrating to a new domain name, you do have to search and replace the database for all instances of the old domain with the new domain. It is preferable to [use a tool like **WP-CLI search-replace**](http://wp-cli.org/commands/search-replace/) to do this task because it will account for serialized array data which can become corrupted if you just do a simple find and replace in a text editor. That tool will also allow you to skip certain columns, like the 'guid' column, which you might want to keep even when migrating domains.

Currently, there is no "better way" to avoid hard-coding the site URL in the database since that is the default WordPress behavior. [You can read more in the WordPress handbook here](https://make.wordpress.org/core/handbook/contribute/design-decisions/#absolute-versus-relative-urls), which explains why absolute URLs are stored in the database.

Comment: Thanks Ben :) It worked. IP was hard code in the DB. We had to manually change it